# how to prove that $P(x|y,z)=P(x,y,z,\delta)/P(\delta|z)$

Tags: probability

Is it possible to prove that
$$P(x|y,z)=\frac{P(x,y,z,\delta)}{P(\delta|z)}$$
without any other info?

Comment: No.  You could show $P(x \mid y,z)=\dfrac{P(x,y\mid z)}{P(y\mid z)}=\dfrac{P(x,y,z )}{P(y\mid z)P(z)}$

Comment: Obviously $y$ is superfluous.  After eliminating it, the relationship between the right hand side and the correct formula for a conditional probability ought to become clearer, thereby helping you answer this question.